# Which method of getting a reference to a struct field is the preferred way?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I've been overwhelmed by all the ways to get a reference to a struct field from a reference to a struct. These are the ways I'm aware of right now:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: i32,
}

let foo = &Foo { bar: 123 };

let bar1 = &foo.bar;
let ref bar2 = foo.bar;
let ref bar3 = (*foo).bar;
let &Foo { bar: ref bar4 } = foo;
let Foo { bar: bar5 } = foo;
let Foo { bar: ref bar6 } = foo;
let Foo { bar: ref bar7 } = *foo;
```

Which of these is the "preferred way"? I assume that field access like `foo.bar` is preferred for a single field and pattern matching for getting multiple ones in one go, but it's unclear to me which of the multiple ways I've listed above I should use for each case.

Comment: You can also add a closure for more fun: `let Foo { bar: ref bar8 } = *(|| foo)()`

Comment: @DenysSéguret You do realize that `bar1` in `let bar1 = …` *is a pattern*? It's just irrefutable. Plus, I've seen deconstruction happen quite a lot in method taking `self` parameters. I would definitely not say that "Pattern matching makes mostly sense when it's unsure".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to avoid the direct access which would be

```
let bar1 = &foo.bar;
```

This is easier to write and to read. You don't need pattern matching here.

Pattern matching is an additional tool, which basically solves two kinds of problems:

- destructure a value into several ones, for example `let (a, b) = c;`
- being conditional ("refutable") in a `while let`, `if let`, `match` arm

See [All the places patterns can be used](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#all-the-places-patterns-can-be-used).

Some of your declarations are officially discouraged. Clippy would warn you about [the ref ones](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#toplevel_ref_arg).